# How to redirect to www.example.com/products from example.com/products in Rails 2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-301

I have successfully used code to redirect my application from example.com to www.example.com

I use the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


  before_filter :ensure_domain


  APP_DOMAIN = "www.example.com"
  NAKED_DOMAIN = "example.com"
protected 

  def ensure_domain
    if request.env['HTTP_HOST'] == NAKED_DOMAIN && RAILS_ENV =='production'
      #HTTP 301 is a permanent redirect
        redirect_to "http://#{APP_DOMAIN}", :status => 301
    end
  end
```

This works fine for links that go to the home page.

However I just realized that if I have a the following url:

example.com/products

The user gets redirected to the home page at www.example.com and NOT www.example.com/products

How can I redirect to the URL the user is trying to access but the www.example.com root and not the example.com root.

In other words if a user wants the following:

example.com/products

I send them to

www.example.com/products

Thanks for any assistance.

I am hosted on Heroku.
I am using Zerigo DNS. When I tried using the DNS to forward all traffic from the naked domain to the www.example.com domain the URL still shows the naked domain.

So that did not work.

Comment: This would better be done by your server not by your application code. You need to catch all the urls that never reach rails such as static assets etc... re-post your question including detauils of the server you are using or even better in your dns settings

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the job of your DNS settings NOT your Rails application.
To do this you need to create A records.

Here is how Digital Ocean suggest you do it

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

So you end up with two A records both pointing to the same ip

```
  @ your_ip_address
  www your_ip_address
```

Have a look at
http://jaketrent.com/post/add-zerigo-dns-to-heroku/

Specifically

> 4. Add Domains on Heroku
>
> Via the Heroku cli, type:
>
> 1
>
> heroku domains:add www.yourapp.com
>
> Note that we do not want to add yourapp.com (no “www”) to in this
>   manner. If you do that, the tool adds multiple A records to Zerigo,
>   which the Zerigo docs clearly state you don’t want. These A records
>   are what will activate routing through the Bamboo stack, which you
>   want to avoid.
>
> This should be the point at which you can refresh your browser at
>   “yourapp.com”. You should see the redirect happen, moving you to
>   “www.yourapp.com”. The routing should be happy on Heroku’s end. It
>   sometimes takes more time for this to propagate, so if you don’t see
>   results immediately, be a bit patient before your start changing your
>   configuration, thinking it’s not working.

Or to do this in your server then an nGinx example might look like this

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

BE PATIENT. It takes time to propogate

You should absolutely NOT be doing this in your application code that goes for ANY environment be it PHP, Rails, or anything else

You have not provided any details of the server or the domain you will be running in so am unavble to provide a specific solution for your environment but the above should be enough for you to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jamesw.  I do have those domains added already and am using ZerigoDNS.  I have even talked to their support staff and followed their instructions which were to add an ALIAS record that points the root domain to the www domain. However, it did not work. I still have that setting and it does not do anything and its been more than 30 hours, long  enough to propagate.  I'm on the Cedar stack of Heroku btw.

Comment: @chell I would raise a support request with zerigo.